# Does such a theory exist?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, emotion, measurement, cognitive-modeling, computational-modeling

Is there any model that describes how people behave while taking compositions of emotions into account?
Such as, how different the behavior of a person is when he is (10% angry + 50% sad + 40% some other emotion ) and when (50% angry + 10% sad + 40% some other emotion)
Are there any books on this type of question? Or some similar books? I need books that delve into these topics

Comment: How would you measure that someone is "(10% angry + 50% sad + 40% some other emotion)"? How would you avoid the process of taking that measurement influencing the emotional state to be able to connect it to a behavior? What would suggest that emotions are something that sum up to a whole at any given point of time?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.